# how to move vertical scroll bar on clicking an element to display the content correctly?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple sections(sec1, sec2, sec3, ..) on a page. This page is opened by clicking a navigation tab (which further have sub-tabs like *sec1, sec2, sec3,..*). When I click on any sub-tab, I want vertical scroll bar move to display corresponding section from that page.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `a` tags and `scrollTo`?... Show some code to better understand and reply to your specific problem...

Comment: Please show us your code! You could probably do it by giving the `div` which has the content a fixed height and apply `overflow: auto` to it.

Comment: I don;t think that that was the question @LinkinTED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `id` can be used to create an anchor to the start of any element. You can then use the `href` attribute of the `a` tags in your navigation tab to link to these anchors.

Here is a JsBin to help you understand better: http://jsbin.com/ogEWIFu/1. The CSS is only to help you visualize the sections better.

Source:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3